# Changing the case of the character in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char changeincase(int, int, int);

int main() {
    int size, index1, index2;
    char string[1000], newstring[1000];
    printf("enter the size of the string :");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter the string : ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("Enter the first index :");
    scanf("%d", &index1);
    printf("Enter the second index :");
    scanf("%d", &index2);
    newstring[5] = changeincase(index1, index2 ,size);
    printf("%s", newstring);
}

char changeincase(i, j, n) {      
    char str[1000];
  
    if (str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90) {
       str[i] = str[i] + 32;
    }
    if (str[j] >= 65 && str[j] <= 90) {
       str[j] = str[j] + 32;
    }
}
```

The above code is supposed to convert the case of the string at a specified index but it is not working. It is generating some random characters every time I run the code. Please help me out.

Comment: `newstring` is unintialized, you only set its 6th index. The rest is random data. Same with `str` in your `changeincase` function. C strings must be `NUL` terminated (with a `'\0'`).. and more than likely you'll want printable characters for the rest of it.

Comment: That function does *nothing* to the strings in `main`. It conditionally modifies a local `str` that was never content-established. The content is indeterminate. And even if it were determinate it still wouldn't be modifying the string(s) in `main`. It also claims to return a value (of type `char`) but makes no effort to actually do so; more undefined behavior.

Comment: Please explain: What do you expect this to do - `newstring[5]=changeincase(index1,index2 ,size);`

Comment: Please explain: What is the purpose of n` in the function `changeincase`

Comment: Did you just ignore the compiler warnings?

Comment: For changing case use `toupper` or `tolower`

Comment: When compiling your code using gcc and flags "-Wall -Wextra -pedantic" I get 6 warnings. These 6 warnings tell exactly what is the problem with your code. **Don't ignore warnings - fix them**

Comment: OT: It's pretty strange to write a function that changes case of exactly 2 characters... could it be that the function is supposed to change case for all characters between index1 and index2?

Comment: When you mean `'A'`, use `'A'` instead of `65`, the same for `'Z'` instead of `90`, etc.. To change the case of any ASCII alpha-character, you can simply change the *case-bit* by XOR'ing with `1 << 5` (e.g. `32`) or using the standard `ctype.h` macros `tolower()` and `toupper()`. See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You could invert case for a single character with a following function:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int invert_case(int c) {
    if (islower(c))      return toupper(c);
    else if (isupper(c)) return tolower(c);
    else                 return c;
}
```

This code avoids using magic constants.

Another issue is updating a **local** variable `str`. The changes are invisible outside the function. Just make `str` an argument:

```
void changeincase(char* str, int i, int j) {
 // char str[1000];
...
}
```

Comment: Using these 4 standard function is the correct way. As an opinion based nitpick I wouldn't put `else` after a `return` but that's not real important so ... +1

Answer (score 0):

In the function changeincase(i,j,n) you have defined an array of characters i.ei str[1000].
That array is neither initialized nor its values are defined by user but you are using it so it will automatically give you some garbage value.
That's the problem.

Comment: While you are correct about `str` being local to the function and uninitialized, I don't really see how this helps OP solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The function `changeincase` should take pointers to the source and destination strings as well as the boundary index values.

You should not use explicit character values such as `65` and `90`. Using `'A'` and `'Z'` is more readable and portable, and for real portability, you should use the functions from `<ctype.h>`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void changeincase(char *dest, const char *src, int start, int end) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; src[i]; i++) {
        if (i >= start && i <= end) {
            unsigned char c = src[i];
            dest[i] = tolower(c);
        } else {
            dest[i] = src[i];
        }
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';  set the null terminator
}

int main() {
    int index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
    char string[1000] = "", newstring[1000];

    printf("Enter the string: ");
    scanf("%999s", string);
    printf("Enter the first index:");
    scanf("%d", &index1);
    printf("Enter the second index:");
    scanf("%d", &index2);
    changeincase(newstring, string, index1, index2);
    printf("%s", newstring);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I see few mistakes in your code as also pointed out in comments in your questions.
Here's my solution(It will inverter the case of the string in between the specified index i.e. lower to upper and upper to lower. Including the indexes.) Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void changeincase(int ,int,int, char *);

int main()
{
  int size,index1,index2;
  printf("enter the size of the string :");
  scanf("%d",&size);
  char string[size+1];
  printf("Enter the string : ");
  scanf("%s",string);
  printf("Enter the first index :");
  scanf("%d",&index1);
  printf("Enter the second index :");
  scanf("%d",&index2);
  changeincase(index1,index2 ,size, string);
  printf("%s",string);
  
}

void changeincase(int startIndex,int endIndex,int n, char *str)
{
  
  //char str[1000];
    for(int i = startIndex; i<=endIndex; i++){
        int ascii = (int)str[i];
        if(ascii>=65&&ascii<=90){
            str[i] = (char)(ascii+32);
        }else if(ascii>=97&&ascii<=122){
             str[i] = (char)(ascii-32);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What made you think OP wanted to "invert" the case of all characters between start and end index?

Comment: What is wrong with `islower`, `isupper`, `tolower`, `toupper` ?

Comment: If a character is changed in your forst if-statement, what happens in the second if-statement?

Comment: What is the purpose of `n` in the function?

Comment: Please don't use magic numbers like 32, 65, 90, ... Use the letters... Example: Instead of 65 write `'A'`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the islower, isupper, tolower, toupper u can use it if u want, n is not required since the Q posted is using the ascii code there is harm in using "magic number"